# C# console application randomly waits for input

Tags: c#, console-application

i made an app and sometimes it just pauses until I press a key.

i do not use any code which requiereres any input or interaction (such as readline or readkey).

this randomly happens like 1 in 20 times after Thread.Sleep and after you press any key it continues to work perfectly.

```
                    if (Convert.ToInt64(timetotask[0]) > 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(timetotask[0]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mylog.log("Task was in the past, executing it now");
                    }
                    int currentbid = placebid(task.itemid, bid, driver[Convert.ToInt32(task.account)]);
```

the first line of placebid is console.writeline("mystring") so i do not see anything what could cause this behaviour.

Does it have something to do with debug mode?

thanks for help

Comment: You could run your application in the debugger and it it seems to be waiting for input use the command *Debug > Break All*. Then you willsee what statement is waiting for user input.

Comment: I have the similar issue, i use parallel foreach loop to fetch some web urls, and sometimes app waits until i press a key, do you find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This could be obvious but if pressing a key in the console makes the application resume, it is most likely you managed to pause the app via the console by pressing a key.

When it is sleeping do you ever press a key to check if it has paused?  Then eventually the sleep ends as it matches the rule and then when you next press a key it unpauses the program...

Michael